# Convergence of a variable in terms of a trig function derived from power series of its inverse function

Tags: functional-analysis, power-series

Since $$\tan^{-1}u =1-u+u^{3}/3-..., u =\tan x $$
we have
$$x= 1- \tan x +\tan^{3}x/3..\tag 1 $$

What is the interval of convergence?

Can $x$ be summed up from powers of any circular trigonometric function ?

Is it valid for *any* inverse function whose series expansion is known?